# Timer cannot be converted to Actionlistener error?

Tags: java, user-interface

We wrote a code for a timer based animation and I nested a Changelistener and ACtionlistener. However, my timer is (in the actionlistener) can't be converted to such, according to the error I get. How can I fix this?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Slider3 {

    public static JSlider slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 1000, 20, 0);
    public static JLabel label;
    public static JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    public static int delay;
    public static int speed;
    public static Timer timer = new Timer (delay, new SliderListener());

    public void main(String[] args) {   
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Legend Of Zelda");
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5, 5, 25));
        slider.addChangeListener(new SliderListener());
        delay = speed;

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        timer.start();

        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(slider);
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.pack();
    }

    private static class SliderListener implements ChangeListener, ActionListener {

        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
                ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(i + ".jpg");
                label.setIcon(imageIcon);
            }
            int speed = slider.getValue();
        }

        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
            delay = speed;
            timer = new Timer(delay, timer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Timer's constructor's second parameter should be an ActionListener, you are passing a timer... what are you expecting / what are you trying to do?

Comment: int speed = slider.getValue(); <-- this assignment does nothing. The for loop seems static, there is no reason to put it in the SliderListener. Why are you using a timer? If your goal is to update Slider3.speed, just do `Slider3.speed = slider.getValue()` in the SliderListener, no need for a Timer.